# How to keep a ScrollView to be scrolled to the Bottom?

Tags: java, android

I have a ScrollView with a LinearLayout inside an I'm adding TextViews. But I always want the last added TextView to be visible, so I need the ScrollView to scroll to the Bottom, when a TextView is added. I don't know why, but when I call scrollto(), scrollby() or fullScroll() after adding a textview, it only scrolls to the textview before the last one.

Do you know a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Code:

I got a Button, which calls this function:

```
private void addRound() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView newRound = new TextView(Stopwatch.this);
    newRound.setText("" + counter + ". - " + timerText());
    newRound.setTextSize(20);
    newRound.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    linlay.addView(newRound);
    counter++;
}
```

After calling this function I call fullScroll().

```
addRound();
sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

sv ist my ScrollView, linlay is the linearlayout inside the scrollview.

Comment: you should probably use ListView for this purpose and use list.setSelection(int index); easily.

Comment: Can I shrink a ListView to be only a part of an layout?

Comment: Could we see the code you are using to determine where to scroll to and to actually scroll the ScrollView?

Comment: sure, gimme a second i'll edit my original post

Comment: yes ListView can be a part of something else - say another vertical LinearLayout. figured these are your ROUNDS with time spent on the game round. correct? you should probably keep this info in a database. First update the db then retrieve the data into your listview and refresh it.

Comment: I need more than one TextView since they all show different data. Yeah, I'm adding the TextViews since I add them to linlay, which is the ScrollViews child.

Comment: Why is there even a problem with scrolling to the bottom in a ScrollView?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I reckon it's because the ScrollView is not quite updated by the time you call `sv.scrollFull(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` Try the following (to replace your second code sample):

```
addRound();
sv.post(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
     sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
   }
});
```

If the above doesn't work, try the following (it's not an elegant way of doing it but it may work):

```
addRound();
sv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
     sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
   }
}, 100);
```

Hope this works!

Comment: The first option works fine with apperently no remarkable performance-issues, thanks a lot!

Comment: Not quite updated. That's it! Finally solved my problem. Did not need the postDelayed, the normal post was sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, the postDelayed code worked always for me, the first code only worked sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener. Add this  code snippet in onCreate() method.

```
    linlay.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
```